# Arduino switch with chars

Tags: arduino

I have a switch statement, but It seems that don't recognize the character C as always print default

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   Serial.println("Serial conection started, waiting for instructions...");
}
    String serialReceived;
    char commandChar[1];

    void loop() {

      if(Serial.available() > 0) {

            serialReceived = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
            serialReceived.substring(0,1).toCharArray(commandChar, 1);


            switch (commandChar[0]) {
             case 'C':
                 Serial.print("Arduino Received C");
                 break;
                default:
                 Serial.print("default");
            }

       }
    }
```

Comment: First try printing the `commandChar[0]` to ensure it is actually `C`.

Comment: nothing; serialReceived is "COMPILE" but commandChar[0] is empty (?!)

Comment: It can't be empty, it might have some non-printable character, for example the carriage return `\r` from the previous line (and it is the case most likely). So print it as ascii value.

Comment: Try with a buffer of size 2. Perhaps toCharArray add the final `\0` in any cases

Comment: true, define the buffer of size 2 solved the problem. Thanks

Comment: This is why I don't like arduino... Where this behaviour is documented?

Comment: I am asking where I can update the doc. I will do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This code seems to do what you want:

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);  
   Serial.println("Serial conection started, waiting for instructions...");
}

String serialReceived;
char commandChar;

void loop() {

    if(Serial.available() > 0) {

      serialReceived = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
      commandChar = serialReceived.charAt(0);

      switch (commandChar) {
         case 'C':
             Serial.print("Arduino Received C");
             break;
         default:
             Serial.print("default");
      }

  }
}
```

Given that you only want a single `char`, I changed the type of `commandChar` and used the `charAt` function of the `String` class.

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using a buffer of size 2 solved the problem

```
 serialReceived.substring(0,1).toCharArray(commandChar, 2);
```